# Does Manga Video still do films?

Tags: anime-production

Does the production company [Manga Video](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=2807), still produce films? For instance they produced the *Ghost in the Shell* movie. Do not produce films any more? If so, what happened?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly are you referring to? If you're asking about the company that produced the _Ghost in the Shell_ film, it's correctly known as [Production I.G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_I.G).

Answer (score 1):

[Manga Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_Video) is just the distributor and co-producer of the anime *Ghost in the Shell*. The production company is, as hungerartist pointed out, [Production I.G.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_I.G). Manga Video only helped in production by contributing money.

To answer your question: Yes, Manga Video sill exists and yes, Production I.G. still produces anime.

Comment: Rather than a producer, Manga Entertainment are more of a publisher of anime (despite what their name implies).